# how to find tags in bs4.element.ResultSet type object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

I am learning/doing web scraping and stuck on a problem, I have an object of type `bs4.element.ResultSet`
which contains some div tag and I want to extract it as we do in `bs4.BeautifulSoup` type object

this is the HTML code snippet which I want to extract
[image]

I want the highlighted code

so I did

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.simplilearn.com/resources'
result = requests.get(url)
web_page = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html.parser')
article = soup.findAll(class_='contentBySegment') #that gives me bs4.element.ResultSet
```

Then, I tried to use the find method but it doesn't work instead I got an error.
my goal is to get the article topic name
which can be seen in this part of that code
[image]

so, what should I do

Comment: Please post a reproducible example and code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.simplilearn.com/resources")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("h4", {'class': 'content-title'}):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
How to Become a Certified ScrumMaster
Top 20 Agile Scrum Master Interview Questions & Answers
Free eBook: Guide To Scrum Methodology
The Importance of Machine Learning for Data Scientists
Introduction to Data Science: A Tutorial for Beginners
The Roadmap to a Successful Data Science Career With the PG Program From Simplilearn    
Google Discontinued RHS Ads: How Does This Affects Online Marketers?
Penguin 4.0 Update: The Best Advice From Experts You're Not Taking
Digital Marketing Career Guide: A Playbook to Becoming a Digital Marketing Specialist   
Cyber Security Tutorial: The A to Z to get started
What is Computer Security?
Cybersecurity Career Guide: A Comprehensive Playbook to Becoming A Cybersecurity Expert 
12 Reasons to Get a TOGAF Certification
ITIL: Key Concepts and Summary
Free eBook: Enterprise Architecture Salary Report
Project Management Learning Series: Fast Tracking Versus Crashing
Top 10 Reasons to Get a PRINCE2 Certification
Free Mind-map: PMP Certification
Prepare for Important Salesforce Interview Questions and Answers
Salesforce Developer Certification: an overview
Free eBook: Salesforce Developer Salary Report
Top IT Certification Courses For a Rewarding Career
AWS Careers: A Good Move for Cloud Computing Enthusiasts
AWS Career Guide: A Comprehensive Playbook To Becoming an AWS Solution Architect        
Reskilling the Government Workforce for the Digital Age
How important is the Abraham Maslow’s motivation theory in developing the project team  
Report: The Future of IT Jobs in India
Upskilling for the Fourth Industrial Revolution
Selling Your Idea to Leadership
IDC Study: How Blended Learning Impacts Training Success
The Top 5 Myths of Digital Transformation
Course Announcement: Simplilearn’s Introduction to Digital Transformation
Skilling 4.0: A Study on Digital Readiness
4 Great Ways to Usher in National Technology Day
Go Programming Language: An Introduction
40+ Resources to Help You Learn Java Online
```

Comment: Dude!! thankyou but I also need those list of code in rectangled with red color so how can I do that I was able to extract these article topic with the content-title class